# How many types of locks are there in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

how the locks are work in the transaction MongoDB

Comment: There is a manual. There are books. This is not the place for such an explanation. [Read the Fine Manual.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many types of locks are there in mongodb?

Mongo DB uses shared (S) locking mode for reads and an exclusive (X) locking mode for write operations, intent shared (IS) and intent exclusive (IX) modes indicate an intent to read or write a resource using a finer granularity lock.

how the locks are work in the transaction MongoDB?

All the answers you require lie here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/